# How to implement dynamic database columns?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to store in db some info about *item*. I have *item_id*, *item_name*, but i don't know in advance how many info will have this item. One of the can have *item_info1* and *item_info2* , while another will have only *item_info1*. How i can realise this dynamic of the columns?. I think only about storing serialize info in a cell, but this way for getting separate *item_infoN* i must to request the full cell data. This is not comfortable way, I believe that there is another way to solve this problem. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use another table.

```
Items
  item_id
  item_name

Item_Infos
  item_id
  item_info
Foreign Key item_id references Items(item_id)
```

You can have as many item infos as you want for any item.

Resources:

- [Foreign Key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)
- [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)